# Mobile app - Node js or ASP.net Web API

Tags: android, asp.net, node.js, mongodb, mobile-application

I'm going to develop mobile app , currently in Android, later it may change to all OS. The back end is "MS SQL Server". 
Confusion is with Server side , whether to use **Node js or ASP.net web API??**

What the app does is - It will validate for the authenticate user and allows to Read/Write their data.

Main characteristics should be performance,scalability and accessible from all OS.

Have idea to achieve the above in two ways.

1.Using Node js, Mongo Db and tool which export/import data from MS sql server to mongo db.

2.Using ASP.Net Web API - [Referring this](http://hintdesk.com/how-to-call-asp-net-web-api-service-from-android/)

Please suggest which one is the best way to achieve.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using SQL Server as backend, I will suggest you to go with 2nd approach (Using Web API). It will be easy to meet all your requirements.

Here I confused with the need of mongo db in Approach 1 : You can directly connect to SQL Server from  Node.js.